# supremum of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

Let $f$ twice continuously differentiable on $(a, \infty)$. Let $M_{0} = \sup f$, $M_{1} = \sup f'$, $M_{2} = \sup f''$.

Show that $ (M_{1})^{2} \leq M_{0}M_{2}$.

Also, How can this be modified for a finite interval?

Comment: But what is your question? Is about how to solve it? or how to modify?

Comment: Both! Sorry. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint:** Using the Taylor's Theorem we have: 
>   $$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x+h-\xi)h$$ for some $\xi\in(x,x+h)$. Then taken $|\cdot|$ we have $$|f'(x)|\leq \frac{1}{h}|f(x+h)-f(x)|+\frac{1}{h}\frac{|f''(\xi)|}{2}h^2$$ which is $\leq$ than $$\frac{1}{h}(|f(x+h)|+|f(x)|)+\frac{h}{2}M_2\leq \frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2$$ Now, if you regard $\varphi(h)=\frac{2}{h}M_0+\frac{h}{2}M_2$ can you see which is the minimum of this function?

Comment: The $h$ which minimize this function give us a better bound for $|f'(x)|$.

Comment: I think a local min is when $h = \sqrt {M_{0}/M_{2}}$.

Comment: Bravo sir. Fantastic solution. How did you come up with that?

Comment: Rather a lo cal min is $2\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}$. Then $\varphi(h)=2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$. And the problem is  complete.

Comment: Generally, Taylor's Formula works fine in this type of problems.

Comment: How does this result change on a finite interval?

Comment: Your question is if the result is still true in bounded intervals ?

Comment: The question as I read it is, how does the inequality change on finite intervals? I think it becomes strict, but not sure.

Comment: am i correct? The idea would be the the derivatives can't grow too large.